# Is there any better tutorials about the rpsec and cucumber in rails 3

Tags: rspec

Need tutorials about rspec with views,model and controller

Answer (score 0):

The [RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) is an excellent resource on Cucumber, RSpec and BDD.

also

[Static Pages](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top) includes getting started with rspec, autotest, great one for rails 3

and

[Rspec with Rails 3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)